# Whether Internet speed be same in tablet computer as in mobile phone?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, android, internet-speed

I'm about to purchase tablet computer for my Internet needs. The reason I felt need for tablet is:

I had been doing Internet in laptop. Recently I started doing Internet in my cell phone Nokia N73. Because of using cell phone, I got the ease of surfing where ever I go & hence I was able to spend much time on Internet. I realize the benefit of using a mobile device for Internet.

As Nokia N73 has limited functionalities (like no multi-tasking etc), I thought to purchase a new Android cell phone.

Then tablet stroked my mind & I felt, for my purpose (of doing Internet) tablet is best. Tablet is cheaper than mobile as well as it will solve my need more than a mobile phone. Now, I'm thinking to purchase Asus Fonopad tablet (7") or Lenovo Idea Tab A3000.

Now, what I want to know is that whether the tablet will run Internet with the same speed as my cell phone. Currently I have low Internet speed. Please note: when I open youtube video on Nokia N73, the video plays very smoothly without any buffering. So, I never felt a need to download the video 1st & then play. Whenever I needed I directly run the video from Internet. But when I connect my cell phone to laptop & then do Internet on laptop using cell phone, I can't think to directly play youtube video on the laptop. As there it's too slow. Hence in laptop, I have to 1st download.

Now please assist me in saying whether I can get the same experience in my tablet as I'm getting in cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

The N73 supports up to 348kbps on mobile network (N73 doesn't have WiFi capabilities)
The Asus Fonepad 7 and the Lenovo IdeaTab A3000 support up to 42Mbps on mobile network and also have WiFi.

Your internet connection will be much faster and you will be able to watch YouTube videos in a much better quality than the N73